# Rabl/JSON view is not being rendered with ActionController::Live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, server-sent-events, rabl

Simply when I include ActionController::live in my Appointments Controller my apptbook view which i request as  appointments/apptbook.json is loaded (i can see the database loads on the terminal attached to my server) but nothing is returned to the browser, the browser hangs waiting for a response. Can't seem to work this out none of my usual html views in this same controller stall out like this, however i just tried my index json which I can confirm stalls out, so when i request /appointments I get a normal html response, however when i request /appointments.json or /appointments/apptbook.json I never see anything returned to the browser.

Is there an incompatibility with ActionController::Live??

I have tried only including it in my events method but it seems to need to be loaded at the top.

Is there a way of unloading it for a few of my methods??

Controller:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
include ActionController::Live

def index

@appointments = Appointment.all

ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @appointments.to_json(:only => [:id, :start, :end], :methods => :title) }
    end
end
       def apptbook
            @appointments = Appointment.last(2)
       end

end
```

View:

```
collection @appointments
attributes :id
node(:start) { |appointment| appointment.start.iso8601}
node(:end) { |appointment| appointment.finish.iso8601}
node(:title) { |appointment| '<a class="patient-select-link" data-id="'+appointment.patient.id.to_s+'">'+appointment.patient.full_name+'</a>' }
```